# How to display User and list of all Books that he rented - SpringBoot, JPA, MySql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to build a library rest api using Spring boot + Mysql + JPA.

My database loos like this:

[image]

Here are entities, repos and services:

**User.java**

```
@Entity
public class User {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer userId;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    *all getters and setters*
}
```

**Book.java**

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer bookId;
    private String title;
    private String ISBN;
    private String author;
    private String issuer;
    private Integer dateOfIssue;
    private Boolean IsRented;

    *all getters and setters*
}
```

**Borrow.java**

```
@Entity
public class Borrow {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private Date takenDate;
    private Date broughtDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id")
    private Book book;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

**BorrowRepository.java**

```
public interface BorrowRepository extends JpaRepository<Borrow, Integer> {

    public List<Borrow> findByUserUserId(Integer userId);
}
```

> I am trying to find a way to display User and list of books that he
> have rented.

I added `findByUserUserId` method to `BorrowRepository.

Also in **BorrowService.java** I added next lines of code:

```
@Service
public class BorrowService {

    public List<Borrow> getItemByUser(Integer userId){
        borrowRepo.findByUserUserId(userId);
        return borrowRepo.findAll();
    }
```

And in **BorrowController.java** added next:

```
 @RequestMapping("/user/{id}/borrow")
    public List<Borrow> getAllItemsByUser(@PathVariable Integer userId){
        return service.getItemByUser(userId);
    }
```

Should I maybe use @Query?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to display User and list of books that he have rented but I am not able to. I thought that maybe with adding `findByUserUserId` in `BorrowRepository` and that method to `BorrowService` and `BorrowController` will do but it's not displaying anything..

Comment: Do you have anything in the database?

Comment: Yes I do! I have added data to tables.

Comment: Where exactly are you missing data? on the repository, on the controller, on the view? have you debugged?

Comment: I miss them on the view... when I use Postman I don't receive any data

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have used_id in borrow table try editing findByUserUserId method to findByUserId and this should work assuming you have populated the database.

Comment: As did try that but I am getting this error: `No property id found for type User! Traversed path: Borrow.user.` I put like `findByUserUserId` because first `User` describes `User` entity and `UserId` that `Id` field.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the name of the method to 'findByUserId' and also the name of the PathVariable to match the parameter.

Comment: I am getting this error: `No property id found for type User! Traversed path: Borrow.user.` I put like `findByUserUserId` because first `User` describes `User` entity and `UserId` that `Id` field.